# What is the best way to represent an Team and player relationship in ERD

Tags: database-design, uml, entity-relationship, modeling, erd

I am working on designing an ER diagram for a football system, i stopped in the relationship between the player and team, as we know the player plays for only one team and team have many players, so the relationship will be

> Team 1...* Player

but how can i represent this relation when the player play in more than one team, in real life the player has a contract with a team, when that contract ends, the player may continue with the same team or with other team, so the relation will be

> Team * ... * Player or
>   
>   Team 1 ... * Contract * ... 1 Player

Is my understanding is well?
Is there any suggestions about the two scenarios?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24444577/3404097) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23690085/3404097) one.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is indeed by looking at the contract:
[image]

A contract relates exactly one player to one team. This model also maps easily to a database model where you can model the association as constraint on the foreign keys for `Team` and `Player`.